# Xamarin Forms Lottie

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, lottie

Hello I'm trying to run xamarin forms with Lottie for Xamarin and it's crashing. I have installed the Forms Package and the Droid Package and I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md58995ca22a59cb7d445dac899fcf4189b.AnimationViewRenderer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.GIC.AthkarApps-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.GIC.AthkarApps-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Also, I've added the following code to the MainActivity Class:

```
namespace EasyNETApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "EasyNETApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            Lottie.Forms.Droid.AnimationViewRenderer.Init();//Reference for Lottie
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

And I have placed the .josn file as an asset:

[image: Lottie video cam json]

Comment: [Here is a tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/bring-stunning-animations-to-your-apps-with-lottie/)

Comment: [And you can refer to this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=61073), try clean, rebuild, restart, delete the bin/obj in your project and rebuild.

Comment: @JoeLv Thanks a lot for your help, but I followed the same exact steps but no luck. I think the problem is because I'm not using a PCL but the new .NET Standard so I have a warning on the reference for that.

Comment: Hi, `ClassNotFoundException` this exception maybe not your wrong, maybe it is complier's wrong，so have you tried  this `clean, rebuild, restart, delete the bin/obj in your project and rebuild`?

Comment: @JoeLv I've tried this and it did not work at all.

Comment: @JoeLv actually worked someway after doing what have you said so thanks a lot you have saved me :)

Comment: Aha, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's better to follow the guide from the scratch, it seems that your error is not related to the Lottie package.

Here is the example for Xamarin.Forms:
https://xamarinhelp.com/lottie-animations-xamarin-forms/

And here is how to build it with Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android:
https://blog.xamarin.com/bring-stunning-animations-to-your-apps-with-lottie/

Answer (score 0):

There has been a bug in the latest versions of Lottie file. Try downgrading some versions back.